# Scrapy iterating over selector yields n duplicated items for number of selectors found on page

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

I have a working scraper that I have built to collect information from a review site. The problem I'm having is that when I crawl a business page with several reviews and try to yield the items, I only get the first item n times (where n is the number of reviews the selector found).

I've read up a lot on generators, and I'm sure it is because I'm not thinking things through correctly.
This is a simplified snippet. Understand that I have a more complex crawler using callbacks etc, but this code generates the behavior I'm talking about.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from yelp.items import ReviewItem

class CategorySpider(Spider):
    name = "yelp_search_"
    allowed_domains = ["yelp.com"]

    start_urls = ["http://www.yelp.com/biz/j-crew-arden"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        # There are 9 particular reviews on this page
        reviews_info = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "review review--with-sidebar") and @itemprop="review"]')
        for reviewSelector in reviews_info:
            #If I print the extracted review selector here, I can confirm that only the first review selector is being used
            #In other words, I expect extract first will extract the one and only result within the revewSelector
            #Note: if I just do extract(), the item property is populated with a list of all 9 reviewSelectors
            #i.e. a list of 9 usernames given to me 9 times
            reviewitem = ReviewItem()
            reviewitem["username"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@itemprop="author"]/@content').extract_first()
            reviewitem["userprofileurl"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@class="user-display-name"]/@href').extract_first()
            reviewitem["userlocation"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "user-location responsive-hidden-small")]/text()').extract_first().strip()
            reviewitem["reviewtext"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]/@content').extract_first()
            reviewitem["reviewrating"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@itemprop="ratingValue"]/@content').extract_first()
            reviewitem["reviewdate"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract_first()
            reviewitem["reviewvotesuseful"] = reviewSelector.xpath('//a[@rel="useful"]/span[@class="count"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield reviewitem
```

This particular code would give me 9 scraped results, but all of them are the first reviewSelector.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your "sub-selector" `reviewSelector` you need to use `.` before your xpath to indicate sub-selector level.

i.e. this:

```
reviewSelector.xpath('//*[@itemprop="author"]/@content').extract_first()
```

should be:

```
reviewSelector.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="author"]/@content').extract_first()
```

Comment: That is it! I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: @matisetorm no problem, that's probably the most common issue regarding xpath.